# Monster taxonomy in the Witcher 2 (for blade oil usage)

Tags: the-witcher-2

There are several different blade oils available that cause more damage to certain classes of monsters, e.g. spectre oil, arachnid oil, necrophage oil and insectoid oil.

Most of the monster classifications are pretty straightforward, but I don't know the correct classification for every monster for sure.

So, which monsters belong into which monster class?

Comment: I was just about to post an answer here when I realized there are more oils available than listed in the manual alone. So further research is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you press "C" for Character, then select Attributes at the bottom right, then Knowledge is the middle of three icons.  Under that knowledge panel it lists the knowledge you'll find more detailed descriptions (if Geralt knows them, via reading books or experience fighting).

It will sometimes reference specific blade oils to use (for example Wraiths mention Specter Oil) but unfortunately still no clear categorization - I'm pretty sure Endragas are Insectoid, but their entry doesn't say so, and Necrophages is listed as a single entry, with mention of Rotfiends in the description rather than the name/category.

Answer (score 0):

Oils are specifically named after they monsters they are useful for. So use necrophage oil for necrophages (lesser and greater), spectre/wraith oil against spectres and wraiths and so on. Alternatively you can use the +10% damage oil which applies to all types of enemies.

It's not a major thing though.

Comment: I'm asking specifically which monsters belong to each group, e.g. what monster type are Nekkers?

Comment: I haven't found an oil that can be specifically used for nekkers however Brown Oil and Falka's Blood work well. I do not think the game bestiary is large enough to have generic types of monsters with particular subspecies hence the oils were named after specific types.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a whetstone for +20% sword damage always. Add a +10% Damage Potion (Rook i think) and get it on.

AFAIK $Oil + Whetstone does not stack , so if the "+20% against specific" for Oils is correct i do not see a point using them at all. Or is the specific targeting effect greater?

Dmg-Potion + Dmg-Oil/Whetstone do stack, so youll can run around with +30% trough buffs alone. :)

Comment: Whetstones? I haven't seen any whetstones in the game, yet.

Comment: @Raven-Dreamer 10 oder 20 are included in the Swordsman Preorder DLC. But im sure i've seen the recipe somewhere, too. Didnt even think about them being possibly nowhere else because i was used to this item from TW1. ill check again and get back here.